# Wordpress REST API: filter by custom taxonomy

Tags: php, angularjs, wordpress, rest

I have a custom post type called "products" and it has a taxonomy called "domain".

I am using the WP Rest API and AngularJS 1.5.1.  I am using a service to get the product posts.  This part works fine.

```
      getProducts: function () {
        return $http.get('URL/wp-json/wp/v2/products').then(function (result) {
        return result.data;
    });
  }
```

This returns an array of products, each being (partial):

```
  {
    "id": 29,
    "date": "2017-10-09T16:21:56",
    "date_gmt": "2017-10-09T16:21:56",
    "guid": {
        "rendered": "URL/?post_type=product&#038;p=29"
    },
    "modified": "2017-10-09T19:58:32",
    "modified_gmt": "2017-10-09T19:58:32",
    "slug": "product-name",
    "status": "publish",
    "type": "product",
    "link": "URL/product/product-name/",
    "title": {
        "rendered": "product name"
    },
    "content": {
        "rendered": "some content",
        "protected": false
    },
    "featured_media": 30,
    "template": "",
    "domain": [
        2
    ],
    ...
  }
```

As you can see, my taxonomy term "domain" is represented by a number, "2" in this case.

However, Using Postman, if I do a GET as described [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/retrieve-posts-by-category-id-or-slug/):

`URL/wp-json/wp/v2/products?filter[domain]=2`

I still get all my products back, not just the ones with domain=2 as I expected.

What am I missing here?

Comment: That doc you linked to is actually really old, and WP have introduced their [own documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference) since including the API in the WP core. You could try the following request instead: `URL/wp-json/wp/v2/products?categories=domain` or `?categories=2` not quite 100% sure which works

Answer (score 0):

It seems WP removed the filter parameter in v4.7. You can get a plugin to add the feature back in [here](https://github.com/WP-API/rest-filter/blob/master/plugin.php).

I just merged that function into my `functions.php` and it works like this:
`/wp-json/wp/v2/products?filter[taxonomy_name]&filter[term]=taxonomy-slug`